# Magento 2: Admin order url

Tags: magento2, admin, orders

Does anyone know why the order id that appears in the url does not match the one that appears in the product?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID that appears in the URL is the ***Magento internal order ID*** that you will also find in the database as `entity_id` in the orders table `sales_order`.

The one displayed with '#' it's called increment_id and you should see it like the ***'SKU of the order'*** as it is usually used to reference the order when integrations with other systems are used. So you will use this ID to identify the order and not the Magento internal ID you see in the URL. You will find this value as `increment_id` in the orders table `sales_order`.

Also the ID you see in the url is a numerical value whereas the increment_id can contain alphanumerical values to it (a prefix and a numerical sequence). Read more here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-site/change-increment-id.html.

Worth to mention that this applies to other entities as well (invoice, shipments or credit memos, etc)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: You are most welcome :)